# eclipse error - org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start()

Tags: eclipse

i have the following error message written to the workspace log file.

i tried several different Eclipse versions and fresh workspace.

```
    !SESSION 2011-01-11 16:56:49.375 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-01-11 16:57:03.820
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (46).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.net.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2575)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(ProxyManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 53 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(ProxyManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2575)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 53 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2011-01-11 16:57:03.862
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1080)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:2305)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2011-01-11 16:57:03.868
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1080)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:2305)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2011-01-11 16:57:03.872
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1080)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:2305)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3304)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-01-11 16:57:03.925
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (46).
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2575)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

i dont know what to do =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstallation of the java package in the current operation system solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

In the Run Configurations, I only selected the bundle to be deployed and `org.eclipse.osgi` in the target platform bundles, then I dont get the error mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [this error](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1090064/):

> You've installed a version of the Eclipse IDE more than a couple of years older than your version of Java. The latest release, Oxygen.1a, will not have this problem. If you must use an older release, check the Wiki page at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9 for instructions on adding the right startup parameters to your eclipse.ini file, script, or shortcut.